# MySQL setup says ".NET framework needed",How can i install MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

i downloaded mysql-installer-5.5.17.0 for installing MySQL in my system,but when i run this i got the following message

> "this application requires .NET Framework 4.0,please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again"

i want to install MySQL for my java application and i don't need to do any .NET application
how i do that?what does the message means?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that message means you need to install the .Net framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message means the installer for MySQL requires the .NET framework to run.  Therefore, you'd need to either download the .ZIP package (which would require you to manually unpackage and install the MySQL server), or, if you just need to connect to a remote database with your Java application, you'd need to download the Connector/J JDBC driver from MySQL.

Comment: if i download .ZIP pakage,can i install without .NET framework?

Comment: You should be able to, though I haven't installed MySQL in Windows for a very long time so I don't remember.  And unless you're running a fresh copy of a really old version of Windows XP, you should already have the .NET framework (at least some version of it) installed.  It won't hurt your system, it will just allow you to run more applications.

Answer (score 4):

I also find this requirement very problematic... specially when most of the time MySQL is not being used with .NET applications... and a clean windows server installation does not include .NET 4 but an earlier version of .NET.

anyway you can install .NET 4 with no difficulty, just download the installer from the following links:

web install: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851
standalone installaer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22833

Roey

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL *installer* on Windows requires .net. And it has been part of Windows since Vista...

This is separate from *running* MySQL or developing in another language

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is windows xp sp3 or higher, Then you can download .net framework 4.0 from website and then install mysql using windows installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17718

hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In order to install MySQL on a Windows computer, you must first have Python 2.7 (not Python 3+) installed.

You cannot run MySQL using Python 3.

Follow [this link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/) to download Python.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need .NET to install MySQL on your machine.  Sounds like you downloaded the wrong thing.

Whatever you tried, pick another one:

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: He'd need it if he downloaded the .MSI installer.

Comment: Hence the advice "pick another one"